# Javascript in head tag of master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have placed the following script in the head tag of my asp.net master page.

What this script is suppose to do re-direct to the `Timeout.aspx` page after specific inactive time has elapsed.
If the user scrolls / clicks on the page, then the time is reset. On running the page I get an error:

```
Jscript engine runtime error: object expected.
```

Code:

```
var wintimeout;

function SetWinTimeout() {
    wintimeout = window.setTimeout("window.location.href='../Timeout.aspx';",
                                   60000); //after 5 mins i.e. 5 * 60 * 1000  
}

$('body').click(function () {
    window.clearTimeout(wintimeout);
    //when user clicks remove timeout and reset it  
    SetWinTimeout();
});

window.onload = SetWinTimeout;
```

Comment: Have you included the jquery script in your master page? The jquery script include must be *located above your* your script

Comment: I have added it in the head section of the page

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the call of setTimeOut

Change

```
function SetWinTimeout() {
    wintimeout = window.setTimeout("window.location.href='../Timeout.aspx';",
                                   60000); //after 5 mins i.e. 5 * 60 * 1000  
}
```

To

```
function SetWinTimeout() {
    wintimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
                       window.location.href='../Timeout.aspx';
                 }, 60000);
}
```

Comment: Still the same error and it is pointing to the     $('body').click(function () { window.clearTimeout(wintimeout); //when user clicks remove timeout and reset it SetWinTimeout(); });

Comment: In [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) you can also write code as string instead of a function

Comment: Put only one statement alert("hello") in SetWinTimeout() and check if you get it?

Comment: Actually the error is occurring in the body on click ... I think I might be missing the Jscript declaration directive.. can you please share

Comment: Does the error occur when the page is loaded, or when you click the page?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not an error because JQuery is not loaded, try the following to run the whole script after the page (and JQuery for that matter) has been loaded:

```
$(function() 
{

    $('body').click(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(wintimeout);
        //when user clicks remove timeout and reset it  
        SetWinTimeout();
    });

    SetWinTimeout();
});
```